# ImportError: cannot import name Upload

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working on Django, django-rest project and as I have searched the problem, it is beleived I have circular problem, but I don`t think so...

Relevant parts of problem are here:

demo/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_auth.models import Upload, UploadForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if img.is_valid():
            img.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload'))
    else:
        img=UploadForm()
    images=Upload.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':img,'images':images})
```

rest_auth/models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token as DefaultTokenModel
from .utils import import_callable

from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Upload(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField("Image", upload_to="images/")
    upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)


# FileUpload form class.
class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
```

and 
demo/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from views import home

from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
import os
PROJECT_DIR=os.path.dirname(__file__)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name='home'),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.home, name='imageupload'),
    url(r'^signup/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="signup.html"),
        name='signup'),
```

Problem is as stated this:

> File "/Desktop/zadnja/django-rest-auth/demo/demo/urls.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from views import home   File "/Desktop/zadnja/django-rest-auth/demo/demo/views.py", line
>   2, in 
>       from rest_auth.models import Upload, UploadForm ImportError: cannot import name Upload

Comment: Is rest_auth on INSTALLED_APPS, in your settings file?

Comment: yes it is on INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0):

You do not have circular imports since `rest_auth/models.py` does not import any component from `demo/views.py`

I'm assuming `rest_auth` is an app in you project. To import `Upload` and `UploadForm` you should use absolute import:

```
from project_name.rest_auth.models import Upload, UploadForm
```

Comment: Now, it cannot find module rest_auth.models

Comment: `rest_auth` is an app in your project?

Comment: what's the directory structure of your project?